# How can I deal with special values in my function when operating on a vector?

Tags: r

I've found the magic of applying vectors to functions I think of as taking single values, but that seems to happen in areas I'm not able to understand which leads to strange behaviors I'm having trouble dealing with.

For example, I have this time formatting function:

```
timeFmt <- function(s) {
    sizes <- c('µs', 'ms', 's')
    e <- floor(log(s, 1000))
    suffix <- sizes[e+1]
    prefix <- sprintf("%g", s/(1000 ^ floor(e)))
    paste(prefix, suffix, sep="")
}
```

It has two problems:

1. It breaks when supplied 0.
2. It breaks when supplied values >= 1e9

So, it's got this nice behavior:

```
> timeFmt(10 ** (0:8))
[1] "1µs"   "10µs"  "100µs" "1ms"   "10ms"  "100ms" "1s"    "10s"   "100s"
```

...but this nasty behavior:

```
> tf(c(0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 1e9))
[1] "NaNNA" "1µs"   "10µs"  "100µs" "1ms"   "1NA"
```

How can I make my function return "0" for 0, and use the "s" suffix for larger values?  Doing the obvious things of an "if" statement and a min didn't work because they operated on the entire vector that was passed in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you use `ifelse` for. For your example:

```
defTimeFmt <- function(s) { #this is just your original function I renamed
    sizes <- c('µs', 'ms', 's')
    e <- floor(log(s, 1000))
    suffix <- sizes[e+1]
    prefix <- sprintf("%g", s/(1000 ^ floor(e)))
    paste(prefix, suffix, sep="")
}

timeFmt<-function(s) {
    ifelse(s==0, "0", ifelse(s>= 1e9, "s", defTimeFmt(s)))
}
```

should do more or less what you ask.

Comment: I think what you really want is cut